# React native web-view azure aad authentication

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, react-native-webview

I am working in React Native application in which the Azure-AD based authentication is implemented via `react-native-azure-adal` library. We could also achieve authentication via `MSAL` library for react.
All is well so far, but recently we got a requirement so render some websites in the react-native's web view.
I thought that the ADAL library's storage will be automatically re-used by the webview and the SSO would happen.
Unfortunately, none of the access_tokens and refresh_tokens from the native ADAL libraries are visible in the web-view. So the web-view forces authentication again.

Is there any way to extend the adal's (or msal's) storage from react-native storage to the react-native-webview ?

Alternatively, is there any hacks in the OAuth2's apis, where I can pass in the access_token and refresh_token of the user and achieve a fresh cookie based SSO experience ?

Comment: did u find solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.. not yet...

Comment: SSO works with the SSO Cookies (not access/refresh tokens) which are saved in the browser and cannot be shared with the webview. If you want to achieve SSO, then your interactive login should happen through the webview itself.